# Cronjob using CURL/WGET

Tags: php, curl, cron, wget

I want to run a PHP script every 15 minutes using either CURL or WGET.

This PHP file is in a local folder:

```
/home/x/cron.php
```

How would I run this using CURL/WGET?

It doesn't work when I try to run

```
curl /home/x/cron.php
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CURL and WGET are more adecuate for URLs like http://myhost.com/cron.php

When the script is offline, you would better run it using php CLI:

Ex:

```
php -q cron.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like this:

`/usr/bin/php /home/x/cron.php`

cURL/wget is for HTTP actions.  If your PHP script is on the same system, you don't want to load it over HTTP.  (You can, of course, if it is accessible over HTTP, but I don't think that is what you want.)  Just call it directly.

Alternatively, you can set the execute permission on your script and throw in a [shebang line for PHP](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-shebang/):

`#!/usr/bin/php`

Then, just put your PHP script in crontab directly.

Comment: DX I feel so stupid! I should have known this!

Thanks a lot! I need a break haha

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CURL or WGET, I believe you'll need to pass in the path as a URL. If you want to run the php script on the command line, you'll need to use the the php CLI