# Cronjob script call: PHP interpreter (CLI), curl or wget?

Tags: php, curl, cron, wget

Say I want to execute a `PHP` script periodically, eg. `/home/user/refresh.php`, I see several options to set up the cronjob:

```
# Option A: PHP interpreter
*/15 * * * * php-cgi /home/user/refresh.php

# Option B: curl
*/15 * * * * curl -L -s 'http://host.com/refresh.php'

# Option C: wget
*/15 * * * * wget -q --spider http://host.com/refresh.php
```

What are the differences, other than PHP not requiring an URL? Are there performance considerations? And which way is *usually* the best? The only question I found [regarding this matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985187/cronjob-using-curl-wget) does not go into detail very much, and I'd like to establish some sort of good habits or best practice.

Comment: There's a clear answer here: *it depends*. Do your scripts require a proper CGI environment (`$_SERVER` vars), or are the completely compartmentalized from the web invocation? If so, a direct interpreter call is preferrable. Otherwise wget/curl doesn't make a difference (in fact, `netcat` could do).

Comment: If it was me and this script is supposed to be private, I would store it __outside__ of the web root and use __Option A__ to ensure that only myself was using it, no point exposing it to the public web if its meant to be private. You never know if a Google bot might index it!

Comment: The title says "CLI" but the crontab excerpt uses "php-cgi". The title is right. Don't use the CGI version of PHP if you run it as a command line. Use the CLI version; it is probably called `php` on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary difference is the security access of the user account calling the script. For examples B and C, the security context is executed as the web server user account. For A, it's the one belonging to the crontab owner. If you use option A with a dedicated account to this script, then you've got finer grain access control, because the webserver will likely have other security constraint requirements/extended access.

Secondly, since you are hosting this script on a webserver at http://example.com, then you've opened up significantly more access to trigger the script. If it's desirable to provide more convenient access to run the script, then this is good. Otherwise it's not only less secure, but it's not as efficient since you also have the memory/processor overhead of running an actively listening web server if it's not already being used for other purposes.